# Editors in terminal mode via serial interface: bad display

Tags: serial-port, uart, terminal-emulator

I have a [Wandboard](http://www.wandboard.org/) target, which I communicate with via its serial port.
I can login and send commands with minicom, the terminal looks normal.

However, whenever I try to use a more advance editor inside the terminal (nano, vi, emacs), the rows are all messed up. For example in emacs, the content is ok just after starting, but if I start moving the cursor around the line number shows up at the wrong place. If I try to open file, the prompt shows up in the middle of the buffer.

I suppose I have to change some settings for minicom, I just can't find which.

Comment: *"with via its COM port"* -- "COM" is PC and/or MS Windows terminology.  A "RS-232" or "serial" port is more appropriate.  *"the terminal looks normal."* -- Because you're using it in a dumb terminal or TTY mode.  *"I have to change some settings for minicom"* -- You have to get both the program you're running (e.g. **vi**) and **minicom** to agree on a *terminal emulation*.  The terminal emulation is a command set for cursor positioning, highlighting and other advanced VDT capabilities (that Teletypes cannot do).

Comment: I see. It is kind of better after enabling "Add Carriage Ret" in minicom (and no Add linefeed), but still strange. I tried to find out what terminal emulation emacs was expecting (I'd like to be able to use emacs out of the box, and still it's broken for other editors as well, there's a chance that fixing minicom for emacs would work for the others as well), but I'm not sure where this information is.

Comment: Apparently, minicom offers two options for terminal emulation: VT102 ans ANSI. None of these seems to make the editors happy.

Comment: It seems like you have an embedded linux system.  Typically one does not set the terminal emulation directly in the editor, but rather by setting the TERM environment variable or similar, and perhaps having an appropriate entry in /etc/termcap  Details of that which you can't figure out from references would be more of a unix.stackexchange question

Comment: @ChrisStratton: thanks to you, I finally found out I could call minicom like this `TERM=vt102 minicom` then tell minicom to use vt102. If you want to put this in an answer I'd be glad to accept it. Otherwise I'll write the answer myself. (I also had to change the Backspace behavior.)

Comment: Interestingly, the above works, but `minicom --term=vt102` does not. Well, it does work better than before, but sometimes a whole row disappears from a buffer after adding a space at its beginning.

Comment: @sawdust I guess `serial` could be misleading since USB is «serial» too. Perhaps just RS-232 would be a better choice, yea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TERM=vt102 minicom
```

fixed most of it, after telling minicom to also use vt102 and changing the behavior of Backspace.

Strangely enough, `minicom --term=vt102` did not.